# How to start a console process

Tags: c++, qt, console-application, qprocess

I'm working on running a process from my windows application, the process is console exe file. I'm using the following code :

```
void compilerWindow::runClicked()
{
    proc = new QProcess(this);
    QString name = "C:\\qtEcoolCompiler\\qt\\vm.exe";

    QStringList args = QStringList() << "codeGeneration.vm";

    connect(proc, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
                  SLOT(readFromProc()));
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
                  SLOT(procError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
    connect(proc, SIGNAL(finished(int)),
                  SLOT(procFinished()));

    outputBrowser->clear();
    outputBrowser->append("Begining Of Execution");

    proc->start(name, args);
    proc->waitForFinished();
}
```

But the problem is the console isn't showing up (not opening) and the procFinished() will be called and console wont open until then.

What should  I do?

Answer (score 0):

try the system() function; it will run the commands as if run from windows cmd

Answer (score 0):

Firstly [The console won't open with QProcess in windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html)

```
Note: Windows intentionally suppresses output from GUI-only applications to
inherited consoles. This does not apply to output redirected to files or 
pipes. To forward the output of` GUI-only applications on the console 
nonetheless, you must use SeparateChannels and do the forwarding yourself 
by reading the output and writing it to the appropriate output channels.
```

So you should be reading the processes stdout with readAllStandardOutput() or readChannel() or one of the other provided functions.  I have no idea what vm.exe does, but assuming the path is correct and procError( int ) is never being called.... the process is running and finishing correctly.

If you want to use the Readyread() signal, you need to [set the read channel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#setReadChannel). But I would suggest using the [readyReadStandardOutput()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) signal instead.